# hdiutil convert -format UDRW not truly editable

Tags: dmg, iso, hdiutil

Trying to add a single file to an existing ISO I ran into a bit of hiccup I can't see through.  Here it is:

Having never done it before but encouraged by reading the advice from this question:
[Add/Delete/Modify files within a Disk Image (.dmg)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228116/add-delete-modify-files-within-a-disk-image-dmg)

I ran:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o EditableImage.dmg givenImage.ISO
```

and although it created a DMG that was was "mount-able" -  I was not able to edit it in any way.  Trying to run

```
hdiutil resize -size 400m EditableImage.dmg
```

gave me a failure with Resource temporarily unavailable.  (I rebooted just to be sure there was nothing using it)

running

```
hdiutil imageinfo EditableImage.dmg
```

indicated it was of Format: UDRW

but I couldn't actually write to it.. and this led me to asking here the question: what am I doing wrong?
[Runnning Catalina on a less than 1 yr old Mac with all updates]

Comment: Please add the output of `hdiutil imageinfo filename.iso` to your question, or post it to e.g. [https://paste.ee](https://paste.ee) and provide the link.

Answer (score 1):

This might help people who are still running into this issue. In my case, the DMG was mounted which gave the error "Resource temporarily unavailable", when I tried to use "hdiutil convert" on it. So, after simply ejecting it, the error went away, and I could use the command with no issues.